# Translate a view from Android 3.0+ to 2.3

Tags: android, user-interface

In android 3.0+, I have the following code:

```
aView.animate().translationX(diffX);
```

Where aView is a view and diffX is some number of pixels to translate the position of the view by.  Does anyone know what the code would be to do this in android 2.3?

Answer (score 1):

It was introduced in Android 3.0 and is not available on older versions, but you can use this: http://nineoldandroids.com/ 
It's a library by Jake Wharton that "includes support for animating rotation, translation, alpha, and scale on platforms prior to Honeycomb".